# TypeError: Expected sequence or array-like, got estimator RandomForestRegressor

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

I am building a Random Forest Regression model using scikit-learn model. When I am trying to calculate the RMSE error for this model, I am getting an error. Can anybody tell me how to solve the error?

The code snippet is shown below:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

forest_reg = RandomForestRegressor()
forest_reg.fit(housing_prepared, housing_labels)

forest_predictions = forest_reg.predict(housing_prepared)
forest_mse = mean_squared_error(housing_labels, forest_reg)

forest_rmse = np.sqrt(forest_mse)
forest_rmse
```

The error is shown below:

```
Expected sequence or array-like, got estimator RandomForestRegressor(bootstrap=True, criterion='mse', max_depth=None,
       max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
       min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
       min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
       min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=None,
       oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

Comment: did you mean `forest_predictions` in `forest_mse = mean_squared_error(housing_labels, forest_reg)` instead of `forest_reg` ? If not then read the docs.

Comment: I do mean about forest_predictions.